# detecting no argument with getopt_long

Tags: c, command-line, getopt, getopt-long

How do I detect the user passed no arguments to a program with getopt_long? I could detect the user calling the program with no arguments by checking argc, but what about the user calling my program with just a dash?

```
$ my_prog -
```

Do I need to include this option somehow in my getopt statement?

```
while(ca = getopt_long(argc, argv, "abc:D:",...)
```

What would the function return?

Comment: I would guess null or 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`optind`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) variable  to determine such arguments:

> The variable optind is the index of the next element of the argv[]
>   vector to be processed. It shall be initialized to 1 by the system,
>   and getopt() shall update it when it finishes with each element of
>   argv[].

For example,

```
  for(int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    printf("Unknown argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
```

You can do this after argument processing to find out if there are any such unexpected arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just start your optstring with '-' character. From `man getopt_long`:

> If the first character of optstring is '-', then each nonoption argv-element is handled as if it were the argument of an option with character code 1

So with the optstring "-abc:D:" you can assume there were some arguments passed if you entered the `while` loop.